# get products from specifique category PrestaShop

Tags: symfony, prestashop, smarty

I am making some modifications in the way that customers explore products in a new page .tpl by overriding category

Is there a function that works but gets products from a defined category using a category ID (rather than the current category) ?

I would like to display products from a specific category

When I put this code, it shows me all the products.

```
{foreach from=$products item=product name=products}

    {$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}

{/foreach}
```

I am using PS version 1.7.8.6

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this into tpl

```
{php}
    $category = new Category($id_category_you_chose);

    $products = $category->getProducts($this->context->language->id);
{/php}
```

see the getProducts arguments, i don't remember exactly what he need.